# surrounding function for adding context

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am trying to write a function which can add a context to those functions given in parameters.

The idea is here

```
object example {

    def withOne(f : => T) = { 
       val a = 1  //some context
       f
    }

    def foo() = withOne {
       println(a)
    }

}
```

I think the context could be passed in implicit.
The idea is to not have the content of f constraint by the surrounding function f should be able to use the context or not.

For now the only way i seen to do that is like that

```
object example {

    def withOne(f : => Int => T) = { 
       val a = 1  //some context
       f(a)
    }

    def foo() = withOne { a =>
       println(a)
    }

}
```

But this forces to declare a 'a' witch is not obvious for others devs :x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot work around this, since you cannot inject an implicit into a function.

There's a [proposal](https://github.com/typelevel/scala/issues/44) to add this feature in the `typelevel/scala` fork, but it seems hard to achieve as of today.

My suggestion here is to use proper naming, so that you won't surprise your users. For instance if you provide a method like:

```
def withConnection[A](f: Connection => A): A = {
  try {
    val conn = ???
    f(conn)
  } finally {
    conn.close()
  }
}
```

it won't surprise me to do:

```
withConnection { implicit c =>
  // db stuff
}
```

Comment: Yes but without exemple it's can be surprising to have to write a function with a connection required. ( I think ).                                            And this is bad and your function already exist and when you must know add implicit c => to all call just because some of your code need more information about the connection. 
The refactor factor and the ugly factor become huge! ^^